# Wordpress Warning - "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Tags: php, wordpress, boolean

I have a wordpress site that I haven't been on in awhile that is providing an annoying "warning." Likely due to a PHP update that is not cooperating with the Wordpress theme. Downgrading to PHP 7.4 breaks the site now and upgrading to 8.1 maintains the errors.

All of the plugins are turned off except for the Swift Framework that is required by the theme.

I'm a definitely in the category of amateur, so I would appreciate any help.

Site: [www.NewOrleansCounseling.com](http://www.NewOrleansCounseling.com)
Wor
The warnings are on the Home and Articles pages:

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 86

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 87

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 86

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 87

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 86

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 87

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 86

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php on line 87

EDIT WITH RELEVANT CODES:
86  $dst_w = $dims[4];
87  $dst_h = $dims[5];

I tried to turn off debugging in WP Config as that was recommended through a google search. That did not work, so it is back on for the time being.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cardinal appears to be a "premium" theme. Have you reached out to the theme developers or reviewed their docs to see if this is a known issue.

Comment: It IS a premium theme, but I haven't used it in awhile therefore my "support" has run out. I can't access their support forum. :(

Comment: Can you add to the question the relevant lines of code in file `wp-content/themes/cardinal/includes/plugins/aq_resizer-1x.php` (around line 86)?

Comment: Ok, added the codes.

Comment: `$dims` is most likely `false`, and searching the web with `"aq_resizer-1x.php"` seems to show up a number of hits with the same error in production websites.

Comment: Going back to that amateur status, how do I fix it? :)